# Ionic Scroll to Element

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have an  with:

```
<span id="quote-{{quote.id}}" ng-repeat="quote in quotes">{{quote.text}}</span>
```

I'm trying to have an index to scroll to any part of the scroller using:

```
$scope.jumpToQuote = function (quote) {
  $scope.quoteSelected = quote;
  var quotePosition = $ionicPosition.position(angular.element(document.getElementById('quote-'+quote)));
  $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('quotes-box').scrollTo(quotePosition.left, quotePosition.top, true);
}
```

However the value of quotePosition.top always equals 10 which is the top-offset of the `<ion-scroll>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i see, you need to replace `document.getElementById('quote-'+quote)` with `document.getElementById('quote-'+quote.id)` , You are concatenating whole `quote` object instead of it's `id`.